# Split a string (word) according to big letters and small letters in c

Tags: c, string

i need to make a program that takes a string with upper and lower letters and the program takes all the lower letters and the upper letters and connect them to a word.
For example :
str = 'SHaddOW'
upperLetters will be - 'SHOW'
lowerLetters will be - 'add'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LEN 8

void newStrings(char firstString[LEN]);

int main()
{
    char str[] = "SHaddOW";
    char smallStr[LEN], bigStr[LEN]; // Fill in the array lengths
    strncpy(smallStr , str, LEN);
    strncpy(bigStr, str, LEN);
    int i = 0;
    newStrings(str);
    for (i = 0; i < LEN-1; i++)
    {
        if (smallStr[i] < 'a' || smallStr[i] > 'z')
        {
            smallStr[i] += 32;
        }

        if (bigStr[i] < 'A' || bigStr[i] > 'Z')
        {
            bigStr[i] -= 32;
        }

    }

    puts(smallStr);
    puts(bigStr);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void newStrings(char str[LEN])
{
    int i = 0, bigLength = 0, smallLength = 0 ;
    char bigLetters[LEN] , smallLetters[LEN];
    for (i = 0; i < LEN-1; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' || str <= 'Z')
        {
            bigLetters[bigLength] = str[i];
            bigLength++;
        }
        else{
            smallLetters[smallLength] = str[i];
            smallLength++;
        }
    }
    bigLetters[bigLength] = '\0';
    smallLetters[smallLength] = '\0';
    printf("\n\n%s\t\t", bigLetters);
    printf("%s\n\n\n\n", smallLetters);
}
```

my code has some problems and it is long,so i want to find another way because my way doesn't work.
prints :

```
SHaddOW


shaddow
SHADDOW
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to help others answer your question. You should edit your question to identify what the problems are. Along with providing more examples of expected output.

Comment: your if condition doesnt seem right. < 'a', but > 'z' . Isnt the ascii value of A-Z less than z? You can use isupper and islower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should have separate counters for big and small letters instead of shared `lengthNewString`:
2. You need to terminate the strings with character `'\0'`: before printing, do:

   ```
   bigLetters[bigLength] = '\0';
   smallLetters[smallLength] = '\0';
   ```
3. the condition should be

   ```
   if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
   ```
4. you're missing `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: I have an error :
    redefinition; different basic types

Comment: `str` should be `str[i]`

Comment: The OP is asking for a better way to do this; these hints are not enough to fix what is wrong with his code

Comment: @TisteAndii But they are, I fixed the code with it. Also, I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <ctype.h>
void splitstring(const char *src, char *up, char *lo, char *xx) {
    /* assume up, lo, and xx point to large enough non-overlapping memory areas */
    while (*src) {
             if (isupper((unsigned char)*src)) *up++ = *src;
        else if (islower((unsigned char)*src)) *lo++ = *src;
        else                                   *xx++ = *src;
        src++;
    }
    *up = *lo = *xx = 0; /* terminate strings */
}
```

And use that function like this

```
char bigStr[1000], smallStr[1000], noletter[1000];
splitstring("SHaddOW", bigStr, smallStr, noletter);
splitstring("The quick brown fox #$@!&&!&@#%# --nocarrier", bigStr, smallStr, noletter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 8 //max length of a string including null byte

char bigstr[MAX_LEN];  // strings for upper and lower case chars
char smallstr[MAX_LEN];

void parse(char * word){
  char sc = 0; //index for smallstr
  char bc = 0; //index for bigstr

  while (*word){  // for every char in the word, till the null char
    if (('a' <= *word) && ('z' >= *word) && (sc < MAX_LEN - 1)) // check if its lowercase and if there's space left in 'smallstr'
      smallstr[sc++] = *word;  // add lower case char to 'smallstr'
    else if (('A' <= *word) && ('Z' >= *word) && (bc < MAX_LEN - 1))  // check if its uppercase and if there's space left in 'bigstr'
      bigstr[bc++] = *word;  // add upper case char to 'bigstr'
    word++;  // advance to the next char
  }
  smallstr[sc] = 0;  //null-terminate each string
  bigstr[bc] = 0;
}

int main(){
    char s[] = "SHaddOW";
    parse(s);  // parse the string
    printf("%s\n", bigstr); 
    printf("%s\n", smallstr);

    return 0;
}
```

Only letters are accounted for though. If (MAX_LEN - 1) is reached for a particular string, any new chars for that string are discarded.

Comment: Code dumps without an explanation aren't very helpful.

Comment: @MorganThrapp what part is confusing exactly? Pretty direct compared to the OP's code. Even added some comments to explain what some variables are for...rest is obvious

Comment: you assume it is obvious to others reading your code but it is always easier to understand your own program then to read others.  It is quite possible this uses operations that the OP has never seen / used before (*word for example).